# Duplicated day numbers when changing the month

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I have a FullCalendar instance on my website, and when I use the previous and next buttons to navigate to another month, some of the days number's are duplicated. For example, I start on November and navigate to December, I'll see day numbers like 2929, 3030, 3131 when I switch to December, and the month of December will start with 11, 22, 33, 44, etc. See attached photos for what I mean!

- [Starting on November](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFpVY.png)
- [Switching to December](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpDuV.png)

Here is the JavaScript I'm using to instantiate the FullCalendar instance:

```js
// FullCalendar Datepicker
    $(function () {
        let el = document.getElementById('datepicker');

        if (!el) {
            return;
        }

        let dateRange = parseInt(el.dataset.range);
        const today = new Date();
        const max = new Date();
        max.setDate(today.getDate() + dateRange);

        function selectDate(date, dayElement) {
            $('#moveInDate').val(date.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
            clearSelectedDates();
            if (dayElement) dayElement.classList.add('selected');
        }

        function clearSelectedDates() {
            document.querySelectorAll('.fc-day.selected').forEach(selected => {
                selected.classList.remove('selected');
            });
        }

        let calendar = new Calendar(el, {
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            height: 650,
            titleFormat: { month: 'long' },
            datesSet: function(dateInfo) {
                console.log("datesSet", dateInfo);
                let newTitle = dateInfo.view.title;
                $('.fc-toolbar-title').text(newTitle);
            },
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
            validRange: {
                start: today,
                end: max
            },
            dateClick: function (info) {
                selectDate(info.date, info.dayEl);
            },
        });

        calendar.render();

        // Select today's date both in the input and visually in the calendar
        selectDate(today);
        document.querySelector('.fc-day-today').classList.add('selected');
    });
```

I have some CSS too to alter the styling of the calendar to be more on brand with this project, but I can't imagine that would be causing this to happen? Happy to share that if needed, just don't want to bloat the post with unnecessary code.

My HTML is simple, I just have a `div` for the calendar, and a hidden input I update whenever the user selects a new date:

```html
<div class="my-8 max-w-[700px] mx-auto" id="datepicker" data-range="<?= $tenant->get_location()->get('moveOutDateRange') ?>"></div>

<input type="hidden" id="moveInDate" name="moveInDate">
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported to the developers.

Comment: Which version of fullcalendar?